# In vue.js, where can I place "app initialization" code?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Specifically, code that runs before the app actually loads. I'm using `vuex` and the first thing I want to do (regardless of what route the user is on) is to dispatch a `getUser` action to get currently user details from the API (or alternatively, redirect if not authenticated).

If I place it in my `App.vue` `mounted` component, I believe it might be too late? Don't children components load before parents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right you want to do something before the application initialize. For that you can just perform `async` method in app initialization. Something like that as an example:

```
function initializeApp (vueCreated) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    switch (vueCreated) {
      case false: // "prevue" initialization steps
        console.log('vue not yet created, prevue steps happens')
        // ...
        setTimeout(_ => resolve(), 3500) // async call
        break;
      case true: // we can continue/prepare data for Vue
        console.log('vue created, but waiting for next initialization steps and data')
        // ...
        setTimeout(_ => resolve('Mounted / shown when app ready'), 3500) // async call
      }
  })
}

initializeApp(false).then(_ => {
  new Vue({
    template: '#app',
    data: {
      content: null
    },
    async created () {
      this.content = await initializeApp(true)
      this.$mount('#app')
      console.log('all inicialization steps done, data arrived, vue mounted')
    }
  })
})
```

I have found some article related to your question may be this help you out. [Link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-ajax-calls-before-bootstrapping-app-with-vuex-best-practices/16392/3)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `vue-router` you can use `beforeEach` to prevent some routes of unauthenticated users.

You can read more [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-beforeeach).

If you get stuck here provide code what you tried with router.

Also [good example of using navigation guards](https://codepen.io/patrickodacre/pen/owjVNK).

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.   beforeEach runs many times and the question is about running a some code once as the entire component is open for the first time.