# Does Vue js have app initializer like in Angular?

Tags: angular, vue.js, configuration, startup, initializer

The question after this introduction:

From this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/sharing-configuration-in-asp-net-core-spa-scenarios/

> Next, we’ll want to handle app config settings in a service. The service will use **Angular’s built-in Http service to request the configuration object from our web API**.

and this is

> APP_INITIALIZER from @angular/core

**Question**

**Is there any component in Vue that does it automatically and potentially displays some UI on error?**, because my approach will end up with a blank page and the browser popup.

I guess on an error I could initialize another Vue app module that is a static single page with an error, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Here is my approach in the entry point of the app main.js

[image]

Comment: Would [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler) help in any way? You covered the config fetching part, so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544329/in-vue-js-where-can-i-place-app-initialization-code

Comment: @YomS. not sure how errorHandler is relevant here, but thanks

Comment: @EstusFlask not a duplicate, "where can I place “app initialization” code?" is different context that simple Yes/No to my question. It's not about where or how, it's about if component exists that would work nicely with Vue/App/Mount ... so far I'm assuming such a component does not exist

Comment: There's no built-in feature and no third-party I'm aware of, AFAIK root component should handle async loading any way. I assume that errorHandler was suggested because you can change component `error` state in case there's a rejection and then watch for `error` updates and throw synchronously so it will be caught by handler, this combo is used in React. There are async components, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State , you can fetch as a part of `component` promise. You can also use promises in Vuex. And you can try vue-promised. Hope this helps.

Comment: @EstusFlask can you take your last comment I up-voted and make it an answer?